# Being drawn to something?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, verbs, transitive-verbs

I know that I can say "I was drawn to someone," but can I also say "I was drawn to something by X"?
I want to imply how I came across a topic that later became a serious project for me. Or should I simply use "come across"?

Comment: Drawn to a person or thing i.e. attracted to. But no "by" in my opinion. However, my attention was drawn to the painting by my friend.

Comment: @Lambie -- "The picture caught my eye immediately.  I was drawn by the unique colorization of the image."

Comment: *I was drawn to it by X* is common enough in Google Books.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, I explained that. No by with a person, a person. Just an oversight.

Comment: @cruthers 'I was drawn to **it** the image' - really?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: No, not really.  Obviously that's a typo.  Here's the redone comment:

Comment: @HotLicks: Your phrasing doesn't sound right to me. "I was drawn to the image by its unique colorization" sounds better. To address the question more generally, when you're drawn to something by X, X is usually a quality of that thing. You could be drawn to a project by someone, I suppose, but that phrasing sounds a bit unusual to me. "Come across" means something totally different.

Comment: *I want to imply how I came across a topic that later became a serious project for me.* suggests to me that whatever drew you to the topic may not have been what induced you to make it a serious project. *I was drawn to Jennifer by her lustrous blond curls and became ensnared by her curious mind.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Come across" connotes a particular happenstance, usually without much meaning about one's internal state or reaction to it.

You can definitely use "drawn to" for a topic. One can imagine using them together, like

> As a child, Mike Duncan came across Gibbon's books at a
> relative's house. As Duncan read them, he found that he was drawn to
> the study of Roman History.